# GitLab "Reply-To" feature using Omnibus not working?

Tags: email, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

We currently are running the latest version of GitLab (v8.0.1) which is installed using the Omnibus package and trying to enable the new "reply-to" feature but nothing is happening.

We followed these instructions:
http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/incoming_email/README.html (specifically the Gmail instructions).  We configured a new Gmail account with lesser-security and we also use the SMTP configuration.

The email, when replied to, is being sent to the GMail account but from there nothing is happening.  The doco seems a little sparse but is GitLab supposed to pick that email up (via IMAP) and update the issue?  If so, nothing is happening.

Our settings in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb (and I had to add the "incoming-mail" section manually because it was not there) looks like this:

```
# SMTP setup
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "aws"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "AWSUSER"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "AWSPASS"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "git.ourdomain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
# gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
# gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
# gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"

# Configuration for Gmail / Google Apps, assumes mailbox gitlab-incoming@gmail.com
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_address'] = "gitlab+%{key}@ourdomain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_email'] = "gitlab@ourdomain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_password'] = "GLPASS"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_host'] = "imap.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_port'] = 993
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_start_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_mailbox_name'] = "inbox"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me installing the last update and restarting the server seemed to solve the problem (I did restart the server the first time as well but it still was not working).